# Flip flop unused states

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, flipflop

in one of my project i have 5 states , to which corresponds 3 flip flops . But 3 flip flops encode 8 states. My question is: the 3 unused states, when I create the Next State equation, are considered "Don't Care"? Cause later I have to create the K-Map using the excitation table for every input of the flip flop. So, what have I to write in the next state of the unused states?
Thanks

Comment: **don't care *much***

as long as there's an eascape route from the illegal states to the legal states it's probably fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an X to mark don't care, meaning the next stat can be 1 or 0.